# How to register this in xml configuration

Tags: xml, castle-windsor

How do I register something like this in the xml configuration (i know, i know, convention over config, but I'm supporting legacy code, so i need to do it in the xml config).

Specifically, I'm unclear on how to register AssignTechniciansFactory with the abstract base class AND the interface type. Normally, i get how to do it for either a base class OR just the interface. But how about registering both to the component?

```
public class AssignTechniciansFactory: 
         BaseAssignTechniciansFactory<Service>, IAssignTechniciansFactory
```

Where:

```
public class Service : BaseAssignTechnician
```

And:

```
public abstract class BaseAssignTechniciansFactory<T> 
                         where T: BaseAssignTechnician
```

This is what I have, and I know it's not correct:

```
<component id="assignTechniciansFactory"
           service="MyNamespace.IAssignTechniciansFactory, MyAssembly" 
           type="MyNamespace.AssignTechniciansFactory, MyAssembly">
   <parameters>
     <dmq>${dmq}</dmq>
     <builder>${builder}</builder>
   </parameters>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @adymitruk said, [you can specify additional services for a component via `forwardedTypes` element in XML configuration](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx#Component_with_multiple_services_forwarded_types_5).

Answer (score 0):

Castle is very forgiving now and you shouldn't have to specify the assembly or namespace if the service and type are unique in all the types loaded. This should work if you had namespace issues or assembly name issues:

```
<component id="assignTechniciansFactory"
           service="IAssignTechniciansFactory" 
           type="AssignTechniciansFactory">
   <parameters>
     <dmq>${dmq}</dmq>
     <builder>${builder}</builder>
   </parameters>
</component>
```